# Do-While loop with user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

How would I allow user input to select one of four methods that print a certain pattern using a do-while loop and no input validation is required. The user just needs to select a number from 1-4 that corresponds to each method.

Comment: You would write code to select one of four methods that print a certain pattern using a do-while loop, without input validation. What have you tried?

Comment: Questions asking for somebody to write code are generally frowned upon.  Instead, post what you have tried and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry to just ask and not post any code but I have to have this assignment submitted by midnight and this is only a small fragment of code in the assignment plus I have no idea how to use a do-while loop. I've been working out the algorithms for the methods for the last couple of days and I am still not done with that.

Comment: @user3440443 Next time, pay attention in class and don't procrastinate with homework!

Comment: My professor doesn't lecture in class so we don't learn anything from him and the class is a "flipped classroom" so we work on stuff in class but all of our assignments labs and quizzes are online. Videos from another professor are posted there for learning the material but the reason I asked this is because it wasn't in any of the videos we have access to so far.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to be magician, and guess what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int methodNumber;
    do {
        System.out.print("Method number (0 to quit): ");
        methodNumber = in.nextInt();

        switch (methodNumber) {
        case 1:
            method1();
            break;
        case 2:
            method2();
            break;
        case 3:
            method3();
            break;
        case 4:
            method4();
            break;
        }

    } while (methodNumber!=0);
}

public static void method1() {
    System.out.println("Method 1");
}

public static void method2() {
    System.out.println("Method 2");
}

public static void method3() {
    System.out.println("Method 3");
}

public static void method4() {
    System.out.println("Method 4");
}
```